# PHP WP For create two posts when theres only one wp_insert_post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this one function that duplicates posts from x date to x date if the administrator accepts the request. All that works. However, instead of getting one post for each run in a FOR function, I am getting two posts.

I use this to call the function below:

```
$start = get_field('absence_startdate', $_POST['iPostID']);
$endRepeatDate = get_field('absence_endrepeat', $_POST['iPostID']);

$start = new DateTime($start);
$endRepeatDate = new DateTime($endRepeatDate);
$diff = $endRepeatDate->diff($start);



case 'oddweeks':
        $this->duplicatePost(round($diff->days / 7), $_POST['iPostID'], $_POST['sRepeat']);
break;
```

```
public function duplicatePost($runtime, $postid, $repeat)
    {
        for ($increment = 1; $increment <= $runtime; $increment++) 
        {   
            $org_start = get_field('absence_startdate', $postid);
            $org_starttime = get_field('absence_starttime', $postid);
            $org_end = get_field('absence_enddate', $postid);
            $org_endtime = get_field('absence_endtime', $postid);
            $org_note = get_field('absence_note', $postid);
            $org_admin = get_field('absence_admin_who', $postid);


            $title = get_post($postid)->post_title;
            $term = get_the_terms( $postid, 'absence_cat' );


            // Duplication starts here
            $duplicate = array(
                'post_status'   => "publish",
                'post_type'     => 'absence',
                'post_title'    => '[R: '.$postid.'] GODKENDT - '.$title,
            );


            switch ($repeat) {

                // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                case 'eachweek':

                    $dup_start = date('Ymd', strtotime($org_start. '+'.$increment.' week'));
                    $dup_end = date('Ymd', strtotime($org_end. '+'.$increment.' week'));
                break;

                // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                case 'evenweeks':
                    if(date('W', strtotime($org_start. '+'.($increment + 1).' week'))%2 == 0)
                    {
                        $dup_start = date('Ymd', strtotime($org_start. '+'.($increment + 1).' week'));
                        $dup_end = date('Ymd', strtotime($org_end. '+'.($increment + 1).' week'));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }       
                break;

                // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                case 'oddweeks':
                    if(date('W', strtotime($org_start. '+'.($increment + 1).' week'))%2 == 1)
                    {
                        $dup_start = date('Ymd', strtotime($org_start. '+'.($increment + 1).' week'));
                        $dup_end = date('Ymd', strtotime($org_end. '+'.($increment + 1).' week'));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                break;

                // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                case 'eachmonth':
                    $dup_start = date('Ymd', strtotime($org_start. '+'.$increment.' month'));
                    $dup_end = date('Ymd', strtotime($org_end. '+'.$increment.' month'));
                break;

                // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                case 'threemonths':
                    $dup_start = date('Ymd', strtotime($org_start. '+'.($increment + 2).' month'));
                    $dup_end = date('Ymd', strtotime($org_end. '+'.($increment + 2).' month'));
                break;

                // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                case 'sixmonths':
                    $dup_start = date('Ymd', strtotime($org_start. '+'.($increment + 5).' month'));
                    $dup_end = date('Ymd', strtotime($org_end. '+'.($increment + 5).' month'));
                break;

                // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                case 'eachyear':
                    $dup_start = date('Ymd', strtotime($org_start. '+'.$increment.' year'));
                    $dup_end = date('Ymd', strtotime($org_end. '+'.$increment.' year'));
                break;

            }

            $dup = wp_insert_post($duplicate);
            wp_set_post_terms( $dup, $term[0]->term_id, 'absence_cat' );

            // Org changes
            update_field('absence_startdate', $dup_start, $dup);
            update_field('absence_enddate', $dup_end, $dup);


            update_field('absence_starttime', $org_starttime, $dup);
            update_field('absence_endtime', $org_endtime, $dup);
            update_field('absence_note', $org_note, $dup);
            update_field('absence_admin_who', $org_admin, $dup);
            update_field('absence_repeat', $org_repeat, $dup);
            update_field('absence_endrepeat', get_field('absence_endrepeat', $postid), $dup);
        }
    }
```

Please take a look at the case 'evenweeks' and case 'oddweeks'. They both duplicate twice instead of once. I cannot see the issue tho. I have ONE wp_insert_post and that should only create one duplicate?

As you can see.... There's two:
https://gyazo.com/1443979280e448defc1a8cd721840a8c

should only be one.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**
Replacing:

From my switch case:

```
continue;
```

to

```
continue 2;
```

**Why?**
In PHP the switch statement is considered a looping structure for the purposes of continue. continue behaves like break (when no arguments are passed). If a switch is inside a loop, continue 2 will continue with the next iteration of the outer loop.